# How can I create a specific trigger that runs a query every time it 30 rows have been added to the metadata table?

Tags: mysql, events, triggers, insert, metadata

I have a fully functional INSERT query. However, I don't want to have to run a query on the entire table every hour manually.

I want to create a trigger that will detect that 30 rows have been added to the table metadata. This is the query, and I only want the query executed for those 30 rows, not the entire database when the trigger detects those new 30 rows.

```
INSERT INTO test.wp_usermeta
            (umeta_id,
             user_id,
             meta_key,
             meta_value)
            SELECT NULL,
                   user_id,
                   '_stripe_customer_id',
                   cusid
                   FROM test.wp_usermeta wp_usermeta
                        INNER JOIN test.subs subs
                        ON wp_usermeta.meta_value = subs.email;
```

Comment: This is not possible in a direct manner. What you _can_ do is implement a cron job triggered watchdog that checks for new entries every few minutes and fires the query you want to execute the moment it detects that 30 entries have been added.

Comment: Add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to the table. In a trigger check if the value of this column modulo 30 is 0 and execute the statement if it is. You can also use the value to filter for the last 30 rows. It probably won't handle exactly 30 rows all the time, as some rows might get deleted before the threshold is reached, but roughly.